# There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405). Request method 'GET' not supported

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

I am trying to make a Spring Rest program, but I encounter the following error when I am trying to call the post method for creating student record

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/rest/api/v1")
public class StudentController {
@Autowired
StudentServiceImpl studentService;
StudentRepository stdrepo;

@GetMapping(value="/", produces="application/json")
public ResponseEntity<Response> getWelcomeMessage(){
    Response response = new Response();
    response.setMessage("Welcome To Student Manageent Page");
    response.setStatus(Boolean.TRUE);
    response.setCode(HttpStatus.OK.value());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
@PostMapping(value = "/create",consumes="application/json", produces="application/json")
public ResponseEntity<StudentResponseModel> createStudent(@RequestBody StudentModel student){
    StudentResponseModel response = studentService.createStudent(student);
    response.setCode(HttpStatus.OK.value());
    response.setStatus(Boolean.TRUE);
    response.setMessage("Student Profile Created Successfully");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

my repository class code is this

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, Integer>{

List<Student> findByName(@Param("name") String name);

//@Query("SELECT s FROM STUDENT s where s.id = :id")
Student findById(@Param("id") int id);

//@Query("SELECT s.Name FROM STUDENT s where s.section = :section")
List<Student> findBySection(@Param("section") String section);
}
```

Comment: try changing  HttpStatus.OK to HttpStatus.CREATED for POST request

Comment: Well, the error says you're using a GET request. And the method is annoated with PostMapping, thus expecting a POST request.

Comment: ya that's problem but i unable to find where i used Get method

Comment: How did you send the `POST` request?